# Putting special Tags by spending reputation?

Tags: discussion, tagging, reputation

Are there special tags that can be put on a post but will cost reputation?

What I mean by this, I have seen tags that can be put by anyone. I have also seen moderator only tags. But I have never seen a tag that costs reputation. Is there something like this in Math Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing. As you said there are moderator-only "status tags" but that's it.

On SO there are also sponsored tags that cost money for the sponsor [How do you go about getting a sponsored tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80332/how-do-you-go-about-getting-a-sponsored-tag) This allows companies to have a 'special' tag for their product. But I think it is merely decoration no difference in function.